# Meaning of "Matting" (in art)

Tags: meaning-in-context

Some artist on DeviantArt seriously recommended a [Matting calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_ArtlanWolf.MatMath) which supposedly greatly aids in the process of *matting*. Unfortunately both the artist and the site for the calculator already assume the reader knows what *matting* is.

At first I thought they mean making images look older by removing sheen / adding matt, but apparently this isn't it - it has something to do with borders. I checked three dictionaries (Webster, Free, Dictionary.com) and not a single definition relates to matting in relation to artwork (other than mat making) or any activity that might require a calculator.

Comment: There's *mat* (carpet), *matt* (not gloss), and *matte* (a mask), all of which have *matting* as a participle/gerund. The spelling of *matte* can be varied to *mat* or *matt*, just to add to the confusion. [A *matting calculator* is calculating a masked area, as per @J.R.'s answer.]

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Plus *mating* with its few meanings and identical pronunciation...

Comment: Um... *mating* and *matting* are pronounced differently. The doubled consonant makes a difference: /ˈmeɪtɪŋ/ /ˈmatɪŋ/

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thanks. I'm horrible at pronunciation...

Comment: @AndrewLeach "Matt" without an *e* for the opposite of glossy?  Really? I have only ever seen that one  as *matte*, as in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matte_display). [Some simple checks](http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=matte+glossy&word2=matt+glossy) suggest that the *matte* spelling is still more common.  Is this a British thing, perhaps?

Comment: @tchrist [Possibly](http://www.crownpaint.co.uk/help-and-advice/product/crown-matt-emulsion.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *mat* is the area between the inside of the frame, and the outside of the framed document or artwork; in other words, the burgundy part of this certificate:

[image]

You can see how all these components fit together with this figure:

[image]

I assume the Matting calculator helps determine the inner and outer widths of the mat(s) used in the frame.

Comment: Until a few months ago, I had never known that as anything but a *matte*.  A *mat* was something wrestlers put down on the floor so as not to bounce their noggins too hard.  Notice how in this [B&H Photo listing for a matte knife](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/132514-REG/Logan_Graphics_500_Matte_Knife.html) the product description uses *matte* but the packaging uses *mat*.